# Android ImageButton cuts icons top

Tags: android, layout, icons, imagebutton

I'm having an issue with android ImageButton. 
My icon in it gets cut off at the top.

the code is following:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
    android:paddingLeft="20sp"
    android:paddingRight="20sp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/registration_1_button_sex_male_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/registration_1_male"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:typeface="monospace" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/registration_1_button_sex_male"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingRight="20sp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_male_blue" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried several hacks which I've googled out but none of them helped.

Comment: I've also tried to add padding inside the LinearLayout and ImageButton which didn't helped and I tried to give a fixed height for the icons and LinearLayout but none of it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try keeping the Image for android:background instead of android:src in the Imagebutton. Its not a solution for all the issues but works well for these kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding :

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

to your ImageButton

If that fails try the other options under ScaleType property

Comment: I tried all of the options with ScaleType.. still same problem

Comment: Have you tried moving the icon? I have found strange behaviour sometimes when in drawable-hdpi / ldpi and reverted to just creating a "drawable" folder.

Comment: Out of ideas I'm afraid .. sorry